# Add as much columns as are rows jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi there I need your help I have this code which adds a new column with 4 cells, but my problem is that what if I add another row how to achieve the columns than to be with 5 cells and so on..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var i = 1;
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add_column").click(function (){
    var trow;   
    var columnContent = ['<input type="text" name="options'+ i +'" value="{{ old('options. + p +') }}"  class="form-control" placeholder="COl ' + i +' ">', '<input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']"  value="1" class="col1" >', '<input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']" value="2" class="col1" >', '<input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']" value="3" class="col1" >', '<input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']" value="4" class="col1" >'];

    for(var i=0; i<columnContent.length; i++){
      if(i==0){
        $('.optionsForm ').find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').append('<th>' + columnContent[i] + '</th>');
      } else {
        $('.optionsForm ').find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').append('<td>' + columnContent[i] + '</td>');
      }
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

This is the html code table with is in Laravel blade  :

```
 <table class="optionsForm" style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th> 


                </th>  @for($c = 1; $c
                  <=4; $c++)
                  <th>   
                    <input type="text" name="columns[{{ $c }}]"  
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Column {{ $c }} "> 

                </th>
                @endfor

              </tr>  


              @for($r = 1; $r
                <=4; $r++)

                <tr  id="option{{ $r }}">
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="rows[{{ $r}}]"   class="form-control" placeholder="Row {{ $r }} ">

              <td>
                <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="1" class="col1">
               {{--  <input type="hidden" name="row_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="{{ $r  }}" class="col1"> --}}
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="2" class="col2">
                  <input type="hidden" name="row_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="{{ $r  }}" class="col2">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]"  value="3" class="col3">
                 <input type="hidden" name="row_nr[{{ $r  }}]"  value="{{ $r  }}" class="col3">
              </td> 
              <td>
                <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="4" class="col4">
                 <input type="hidden" name="row_nr[{{ $r  }}]"  value="{{ $r  }}" class="col4">
              </td>
              <input type="hidden" value="[0]" class="row_col_nr{{ $r  }}">

            </tr>
            @endfor
            <tr> 
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Can someone give me a little help here please I am stuck .

Comment: Could you please add the HTML of the `table` to the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan   I editted my code